# Fluent NHibernate Order by Property in related Entity using QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-order-by

I have items and itemgroup tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE [items](
    [item_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [item_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [group_id] [int] NOT NULL   
)

CREATE TABLE [itemgroup](
    [group_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [group_name] [varchar](50) NULL 
)
```

and here are mapping classes for these entities:

```
public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
        Table("items");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("item_id");
        Map(x => x.Name).Column("item_name");
        References(x => x.ItemGroup).Column("group_id").Fetch.Join();            
    }
}
public class ItemGroupMap : ClassMap<ItemGroup>
{
    public ItemGroupMap()
    {
        Table("itemgroup");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("group_id");
        Map(x => x.Name).Column("group_name");
    }
}
```

**How can I get all items from the database ordered by group name using QueryOver?**

I know how to accomplish it using Criteria (using alias).

```
var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<Item>()
                      .CreateAlias("ItemGroup", "group")
                      .AddOrder(Order.Asc("group.Name"));
```

I tried to create ItemGroup alias and use it with QueryOver, but my result was sorted by item name not by itemgroup name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would look something like this:

```
Item itemAlias = null;
ItemGroup itemGroupAlias = null; 

session.QueryOver<Item>(() => itemAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => itemAlias.ItemGroup, () => itemGroupAlias)
    .OrderBy(() => itemGroupAlias.Name).Asc;
```

Comment: @Cole W, hi, I have a query with 5 relations. And any column of those relations can be used as SortColumn. I can take the sort column as string. How can we use your method for string column names ?

Comment: @whitestream I'm not sure exactly what you mean here.  You are mapping your columns to C# objects.  Why would you use these string column names over the Queryover syntax used above?  It may help to post a new question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Cole W, I add a new question for this and try to explain it in detail. Thanks
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889980/nhibernate-queryover-how-to-make-dynamic-sorting-for-joined-queries